# Distance between color change in playing cards

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a regular well shuffled set of playing cards consisting of 52 cards (26 red and 26 black). What's the average length of a run of same-colored cards?
Ex: If the sequence of the first 10 cards are: R R R B R B B B B R the number is 10/5=2 since we have 5 sequences within the 10 cards, but what is the average for 52 cards.

For 4 cards (2 distinct red and 2 distinct black) we have the 24 combinations of the sequence and already here I find it confusing how to approach the problem. Any suggestions?
I guess I have to use the hypergeometric distribution to somehow compute the probability of drawing a sequence of a given length.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Can you answer the question for a deck of $2$ cards, or one of $4$ cards?

Comment: btw in your example why is it $10/5$ and not $10/4$, aren't there $4$ color changes in the sequence?

Comment: I thought about this a well. But then I thought, that if I split the cards into on pile per sequence and computed the average number of cards in each pile 5  would make sense. However, since I made the problem my self I decided, that it is a minor detail to the problem since it will always be +-1 depending on the interpretation of the problem. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: The problem you describe by example seems to be "what's the average length of a run of same-colored cards"; the "number that must be drawn for the color to change" would (in English) typically mean "starting with the first card in the deck, you draw cards until you get one of a different color, and then compute the length of the same-color sequence before that color-change" (i.e., you're estimating the length of a *single* run of cards, starting at the first. Can you make clear which one of these you really want?

Comment: I see your point. I meant the the first case and it should be clearer now. Thank you.

Comment: For a large number of cards, the answer will be about $2$, in that about half the runs will be of length $1$, about half of the remainder of length $2$, about half of the rest of length $3$ and so on

Comment: For your four cards example, you could say: the probability there are $2$ runs with average length $\frac42$ is $\frac13$, the probability there are $3$ runs with average length $\frac43$ is $\frac13$, and the probability there are $4$ runs with average length $\frac44$ is $\frac13$, giving an overall expected average run length of $\frac{13}9 \approx 1.44$

Answer (score 2):

This is about the average length of runs in binary words of length $2n$ having exactly $n$ zeros and $n$ ones. The total number of admissible words is given by $A_n={2n\choose n}$, and the numbers $a_k$ of admissible words with exactly $k$ runs are given by
$$\eqalign{a_{2r}&=2{n-1\choose r-1}^2\qquad\qquad\quad(1\leq r\leq n)\ ,\cr
a_{2r+1}&=2{n-1\choose r}{n-1\choose r-1}\qquad(1\leq r\leq n-1)\ .\cr}$$
(For the first line we can choose to begin with a $0$ or a $1$. Then we have to put $r-1$ separators in the $n-1$ spaces between $n$ stars; this separately for the zeros and the ones. The second line is explained similarly.)

The expected length $E(n)$ of the observed runs is then given by
$$E(n)={2n\over A_n}\left(\sum_{r=1}^n {a_{2r}\over 2r}+\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}{a_{2r+1}\over 2r+1}\right)\ .$$
The following figure shows a plot of the resulting values. As expected one has $\lim_{n\to\infty}E(n)=2$. In particular $E(26)=1.96151$.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, the remaining difference from $2$ is a lot greater than I'd expected.

Comment: Is your chart $x$-axis for the total number of cards and your $E(26)$ for half the total?

Comment: @Henry: Sorry. The input was ${\tt ListPlot[Table[{2 n, erw[n]}, \{n, 2, 20\}]]}$, where ${\tt erw[n]}$ stands for $E(n)$.